# Python Nested Condition Propagation

Tags: python

I have the following situation:

1) If **condition1** is False run method.

2) If **condition1** is True and **condition2** False, run method. I am doing this by setting flags, am i overcomplicating something?

```
condition1 = False
condition2 = True
dirty = False

if condition1:
    if condition2:
        dirty = True
        print "dirty"


if not condition1 or dirty:
    print "run()"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic essentially boils down to `!condition1 | condition2`, which is `not condition1 or condition2` (or `condition2 or not condition1`) in Python.

Thus, you can rewrite your code as:

```
if not condition1 or condition2:
    # run method
```

Comment: Yeah... breaking down my code to this simple example makes it more visible. THanks RUshy

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it, it would seem that the `dirty` scenario would occur if both `condition1` and `condition2` were `True`.

The logic you desire could be achieved by adding parentheses to `if not (condition1 or dirty):`. Writing it this way means that the only way we *don't* invoke the method is if `condition1` and `dirty` are both `True`, which is the only case not covered by your statements.

However, you can indeed achieve this logic without setting flags, and I would offer that it's preferable to do so:

```
if not condition1 or (condition1 and not condition2):
    run()
```

which can be simplified to:

```
if not condition1 or not condition2:
    run()
```

because if `condition1` is indeed not true, the first condition is already satisfied, and Python goes ahead and invokes the method. Only if it *is* true does Python need to check the other half of the 'or' statement, so in the event that we're checking the status of `condition2`, we can already assume that `condition1` is `True`.

Note that in an `if not a or b` statement, the `not` does not distribute, which can be verified by checking in the repl:

`>>> not False or True`

`True`